# Use of "In order to" and "because" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I think that use of "In order to" and "because" is not good together in the following sentences.

> **In order to** properly predict the interaction between tip leakage flow
>   and suction surface of the blade, tip clearance is considered in this
>   study **because** tip leakage flow is one of the most important secondary
>   flow in turbomachinery rotors.

I re-write them as follows:

> Tip clearance is considered in this study in order to properly predict
>   the interaction between tip leakage flow, one of the most important
>   secondary flow in turbomachinery rotors, and suction surface of the
>   blade.

Am i right?

Comment: I would have to agree with your result, but this may border proofreading.

Comment: I think the sentence is fine the way it is. Your question is not even editing. It is rewriting. You have introduced a mistake in yours: interaction between A and B. You have no B.

Comment: @Lambie B is there.  It's "suction surface of the blade".  The phrase in the middle makes the sentence heavy and hard to parse, but aside from a few grammatical errors I agree it's fine.

Comment: @Andrew Oh, right. Well, that's really hard to read. I prefer the first sentence. It was fine.

Comment: To properly predict the interaction between tip leakage flow and suction surface of the blade, tip clearance is considered in this study because tip leakage flow is one of the most important secondary flows in turbine [??]rotors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tip clearance is considered in this study in order to properly predict the interaction between tip leakage flow, one of the most important secondary flow in turbomachinery rotors, and suction surface of the blade.

A couple of issues before I address the question of "in order to ... because".

1. I would say "**the** tip leakage flow" and "**the** suction surface of the blade".  "Flow" can be countable or uncountable, while "surface" is countable so I'd consider both countable.  You could say "between tip leakage flow ... and the suction surface of the blade" but when listing two things I like to use the same structure, where possible.
2. It should be "one of the most important secondary **flows** in ..."  The "one of ..." structure requires a plural.

Otherwise this sentence is fine, but you lose part of the meaning of the original sentence.  The reason you are measuring tip leakage flow is *because* it is important.  Without the *because* you're just adding descriptive detail without causation.